# Convergence of series $ \sum_n \left(\frac{\alpha -(x+1) }{n}+\frac{\alpha -(x+1)^2 }{n^2}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb {R}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb {N}$. We consider the sequence $(u_n)_n $ defined by:
$$
u_n=\frac{\alpha -(x+1) }{n}+\frac{\alpha -(x+1)^2 }{n^2}
$$

**Problem** :
Study, according to the real $\alpha $, the nature of the series $\sum_n u_n $.

We say that: if $\alpha=x+1$ the series $\sum_n u_n $ is convergent and $\alpha=(x+1)^2$ the series  $\sum_n u_n $ is divergent. In idea please for $\alpha\neq x+1, (x+1)^2$.

Comment: Hint: You can compare it to other series, e.g. harmonic series and the Basel problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$0 \leq\left|\frac{\alpha-(x+1)^2}{n^2}\right| \leq \frac{|\alpha|+(x+1)^2}{n^2}$$

which is the general term of a convergent series, so the series $\sum \frac{\alpha-(x+1)^2}{n^2}$ is always absolutely convergent, hence is convergent.

So your series has the same nature as the series $\sum \frac{\alpha-(x+1)}{n}$.

If $\alpha=x+1$, then the general term is $0$, hence the series converges.

If $\alpha \neq x+1$, then the general term is a non-zero multiple of $1/n$ which is the general term of a divergent series, hence the series diverges.

To conclude, your original series converges iff $\alpha=x+1$.